# dnsmasq: failed to bind DHCP server socket: Address already in use

Tags: dnsmasq

I have a box setup as a PXE server.
The interface that will provide DHCP leases is eno3.
dnsmasq is installed and provides tftp service
** bind is not installed - Ubunutu 18.04 **

```
Error: dnsmasq: failed to bind DHCP server socket: Address already in use
```

However, netstat indicates dnsmasq has control of port 67. (DHCP)

Could someone tell me why I get this error?

netplan yaml, ifconfig, netstat -aunp and dnsmasq run error here:

```
root@pxebooter:~# dnsmasq
dnsmasq: failed to bind DHCP server socket: Address already in use

root@pxebooter:~# more /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
      version: 2
#     renderer: networkd
      ethernets:
        eno1:
            addresses: [10.1.9.199/24]
            gateway4: 10.1.9.254
            nameservers:
                    addresses: [205.171.3.65,205.171.2.65]
            dhcp4: false
        eno2:
            addresses: [10.1.100.11/24]
            gateway4: 10.1.100.100
            dhcp4: false
            optional: false

        eno3:
            addresses: [10.1.200.1/24]
            gateway4: 10.1.200.1
            dhcp4: false
            optional: false

root@pxebooter:~# ifconfig
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.1.9.199  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.1.9.255
        inet6 fe80::1618:77ff:fe60:c571  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 14:18:77:60:c5:71  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7695  bytes 1124240 (1.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 742  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2133  bytes 228533 (228.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 94

eno2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 14:18:77:60:c5:72  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 95

eno3: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 14:18:77:60:c5:73  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 97

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 130  bytes 10266 (10.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 130  bytes 10266 (10.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

root@pxebooter:~# grep -v '^#' /etc/dnsmasq.conf
port=0
interface=eno3
dhcp-range=100.1.200.50,10.1.200.150,12h
dhcp-boot=pxelinux.0
enable-tftp
tftp-root=/home/pxe
tftp-no-fail
dhcp-lease-max=99
dhcp-leasefile=/home/pxe/leases
dhcp-authoritative
dhcp-script=/bin/echo

root@pxebooter:~# netstat -aunp
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
udp    15360      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           1356/systemd-resolv
udp    33600      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           1877/dnsmasq
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:69              0.0.0.0:*                           1877/dnsmasq
udp6       0      0 :::69                   :::*                                1877/dnsmasq

root@pxebooter:~# tftp localhost
tftp> get test.txt
Received 17 bytes in 0.0 seconds
tftp> quit

root@pxebooter:~# dnsmasq
dnsmasq: failed to bind DHCP server socket: Address already in use
root@pxebooter:~# dnsmasq -h
```

Comment: Who has the port before you start dnsmasq?

Comment: It appears that something has already started dnsmasq and you are attempting to start it again on the same port, which is failing as the port is already in use.  If dnsmasq is already started and running why do you need to run it again?  If you need to restart dnsmasq, you should find out what is starting it for you and handle it through that (possibly netplan or systemd).

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is embarrassing.

The reason eno3 is unable to bind to a network address is my network address is wrong.  I should have looked at the syslog first.

```
Aug 14 10:47:52 pxebooter systemd[1]: Started dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
Aug 14 10:49:02 pxebooter dnsmasq-dhcp[2769]: DHCP range 10.1.200.150 -- 100.1.200.50 is not consistent with netmask 255.255.255.0
Aug 14 10:49:02 pxebooter dnsmasq-dhcp[2769]: no address range available for DHCP request via eno3
```

Apparently 10.x.x.x and 100.x.x.x don't fall within the range of the /24 subnet mask.

I don't want to admit how much time I wasted because I didn't notice an extra zero.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

`dnsmasq` is already running, and it's listening on port 67, which is why you get that message.  If you stop the `dnsmasq` service, you'll be able to run it by hand.

Comment: Good point.  The thing that made me think it wasn't running was I hooked up a computer to the eno3 port and it did not receive a DHCP lease.  Is there anyway to trace the process of the DHCP request/response?  Currently the requesting computer just hangs waiting for a lease. (dnsmasq not running would be a reasonable excuse for not getting a dhcp lease.)  However that doesn't appear to be the issue here.

Comment: any idea why `ifconfig` doesn't show the IP addresses on `en02` and `en03`?  One thing I would try is having `tcpdump` listen on `en03` and seeing if you are even seeing the DHCP request.  Then work from there.  But the missing IP on en03 may be an issue.

Answer (score -1):

all you need to do is to just move dnsmasq.conf file to either root folder or to dnsmasq.d folder..  you can try both, in my case moving the file to dnsmasq.d folder worked. cheers :)